# In Apache Spark, how to check if an RDD has been fully computed and persisted in memory?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

RDD (namely, its partititons) in Apache Spark are lazily computed, but sometimes I want to reuse the result of an RDD if all its partitions are already computed and the results are in memory, and do some thing else if they are not (e.g. some optimization to the execution plan of the result). Is it possible to use RDD's API to check this?

Comment: Agreed, it is already answered in that question. Please delete this one

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check the RDD details in web UI. The storage tab in web UI will give you the list of RDDs and percentage of them being persisted. You do have a REST API as well for the same. But, i would prefer checking them in Web UI. Every spark application will have a web UI, normally will have with port 4040 or 4041.

[REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api)

Some more details:

https://blueplastic.gitbooks.io/how-to-light-your-spark-on-a-stick/content/spark_web_uis/spark_storage_ui.html

Let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: @tribbloid wants to change the course of action in his code, so checking the WEBUI seems not to be an option for him